# Header-down show on scroll-up : JavaScript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I tried to make a header-down from certain models found on the internet, after some modification, my first model was functional (first example), when we scroll up it reappears directly.

After adding it to the code of a page on my website, it just didn't work anymore.
In this menu-header, I added my logo, some links and a menu-wrapper, I have the impression that these additions must be integrated into the JavaScript code, but I don't know how to do ...

### Example 1:

```js
/*------------------ Header scroll --------------------------*/

$(function(){ 

var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 100;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);


function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    
    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('header_down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('header_down');
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
};

});
```

```css
/* ------loader------ */
#contenant{
width:auto;
}

.header_down{
    position: fixed;
    display: inline;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    height: 90px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    top: 0;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    z-index: 104;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 19px;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

/*----------------------- PAGE TRAVAUX --------------------*/

.grille{
position:relative;
margin-top: 120px;
z-index: 97;
width: 100%;
height: 1800px;
background: #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>

       <div id="contenant">
        <header class="header_down"> 
          </header>
        

        <div class="grille">

  </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Example 2:

```js
/*------------------ Header scroll --------------------------*/

$(function(){ 

var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 100;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);


function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    
    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('header_down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('header_down');
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
};

});
```

```css
h1 { 
color: #fcfcfc;
font-size: 28px;
font-family: Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial," sans-serif";
}

.header_down{
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 104;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
}
.hide_header #header{
opacity:0;
}
.grille{
position:relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: 40;
height: 1800px;
background: #f0f0f0;
}

.menubar{
position: absolute;
right:4%;
top: 40%;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: .8;
transition: all .4s ease;
}
.menubar span{
position: relative;
background-color:transparent;
height:3px;
width: 20px;
display: block;
margin:6px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
.menubar .first-span{
width:35px;
}
.menubar .first-span::before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
height: 120%;
width: 100%;
top:0;
right:0;
background-color: #fff;
transition: all .5s ease;
}
.menubar .second-span{
width:35px;
}
.menubar .second-span::before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
height: 120%;
width: 100%;
top:0;
right:0;
background-color:#fff;
transition: all .3s ease;
}
.menubar .third-span{
width:35px;
}
.menubar .third-span::before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
height: 120%;
width: 100%;
top:0;
right:0;
background-color:#fff;
transition: all .3s ease;
}
.menubar:hover .second-span::before , .menubar:hover .first-span::before , .menubar:hover .third-span::before {
height: 100%;
}
.menubar:hover{
opacity: 1;
}

.header_down .logoInit{ /* lookitsgraphic fermé */
position: absolute;
top: 35%;
left: 2.5%;
opacity: .8;
transition: all .4s ease;
cursor : none;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
border: 5px solid #fcfcfc;
}
.header_down .logoInit:hover{
opacity: 1;
}
.social-media-links{
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 23px;
position: absolute;
padding: 10px;
height: auto;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.social-media{
color: white;
width:  30px;
opacity: .8;
margin: 15px;
transition: all .4s ease;
}
.social-media:hover{
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(1.5);
}
.navigation-links{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
font-family:poppins;
}
.navigation-links a{
padding:10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-size: 40px;
opacity: .7;
color: rgba(252, 252, 252, 0);
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fcfcfc;
transition: all .4s ease;
}
.navigation-links a:hover{
opacity: 1;
color: rgba(252, 252, 252, 1);
-webkit-text-stroke: 0px;
}
.navigation-links a::before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left: 50%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
align-items: center;
font-size: 9vw;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: monoton;
color:rgb(255, 255, 255,.1);
z-index: 1;
pointer-events: none;
opacity: 0;
letter-spacing: 100px;
transition: all .4s ease;
}
.navigation-links a:hover::before{
content: attr(data-text);
opacity: 1;
letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.colors{
color: #fff;
}

.html{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
left: 5%;
top:30%;
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="all">      

         <header class="header_down"> 
                <h1><a class="logoInit" alt="logo">lookitsgraphic</a>
                </h1>
                                <div class="social-media-links">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img src="https://lookitsgraphic.com/src/picto/Instagram.png" class="social-media" alt="instagram-logo">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="https://lookitsgraphic.com/src/picto/Phone.png" class="social-media" alt="phone-logo">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" target="_top">
                        <img src="https://lookitsgraphic.com/src/picto/Mail.png" class="social-media" alt="mail-logo">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="https://lookitsgraphic.com/src/picto/Eye.png" class="social-media" alt="eye-logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="menubar">
                    <span class="first-span"></span>
                    <span class="second-span"></span>
                    <span class="third-span"></span>
                </div>

          </header>
          
         <div class="grille">
         
          
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

If any one understand where to fix this problem.

Thank you for your consideration in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem was the lack of `jquery` plugin. The plugin needs to be included in the `head` tag. Like this:

```
<head>
   ...
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ...
</head>
```

Also, set `position: fixed` for `.header_down`. In this case, the header will be fixed when scrolling down, and will appear when scrolling up.

```js
/*------------------ Header scroll --------------------------*/

$(function(){ 

var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 100;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);


function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
 
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){

        $('header').removeClass('header_down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
 
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('header_down');
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
};

});
```

```css
h1 { 
color: #fcfcfc;
font-size: 28px;
font-family: Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial," sans-serif";
}

.header_down{
    height: 120px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 104;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
}
.hide_header #header{
opacity:0;
}
.grille{
position:relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: 40;
height: 1800px;
background: #f0f0f0;
}

.menubar{
position: absolute;
right:4%;
top: 40%;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: .8;
transition: all .4s ease;
}
.menubar span{
position: relative;
background-color:transparent;
height:3px;
width: 20px;
display: block;
margin:6px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
.menubar .first-span{
width:35px;
}
.menubar .first-span::before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
height: 120%;
width: 100%;
top:0;
right:0;
background-color: #fff;
transition: all .5s ease;
}
.menubar .second-span{
width:35px;
}
.menubar .second-span::before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
height: 120%;
width: 100%;
top:0;
right:0;
background-color:#fff;
transition: all .3s ease;
}
.menubar .third-span{
width:35px;
}
.menubar .third-span::before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
height: 120%;
width: 100%;
top:0;
right:0;
background-color:#fff;
transition: all .3s ease;
}
.menubar:hover .second-span::before , .menubar:hover .first-span::before , .menubar:hover .third-span::before {
height: 100%;
}
.menubar:hover{
opacity: 1;
}

.header_down .logoInit{ /* lookitsgraphic fermé */
position: absolute;
top: 35%;
left: 2.5%;
opacity: .8;
transition: all .4s ease;
cursor : none;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
border: 5px solid #fcfcfc;
}
.header_down .logoInit:hover{
opacity: 1;
}
.social-media-links{
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 23px;
position: absolute;
padding: 10px;
height: auto;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.social-media{
color: white;
width:  30px;
opacity: .8;
margin: 15px;
transition: all .4s ease;
}
.social-media:hover{
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(1.5);
}
.navigation-links{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
font-family:poppins;
}
.navigation-links a{
padding:10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-size: 40px;
opacity: .7;
color: rgba(252, 252, 252, 0);
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fcfcfc;
transition: all .4s ease;
}
.navigation-links a:hover{
opacity: 1;
color: rgba(252, 252, 252, 1);
-webkit-text-stroke: 0px;
}
.navigation-links a::before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left: 50%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
align-items: center;
font-size: 9vw;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: monoton;
color:rgb(255, 255, 255,.1);
z-index: 1;
pointer-events: none;
opacity: 0;
letter-spacing: 100px;
transition: all .4s ease;
}
.navigation-links a:hover::before{
content: attr(data-text);
opacity: 1;
letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.colors{
color: #fff;
}

.html{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
left: 5%;
top:30%;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
        <div id="all">      

         <header class="header_down"> 
                <h1><a class="logoInit" alt="logo">lookitsgraphic</a>
                </h1>
                                <div class="social-media-links">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img src="https://lookitsgraphic.com/src/picto/Instagram.png" class="social-media" alt="instagram-logo">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="https://lookitsgraphic.com/src/picto/Phone.png" class="social-media" alt="phone-logo">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" target="_top">
                        <img src="https://lookitsgraphic.com/src/picto/Mail.png" class="social-media" alt="mail-logo">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="https://lookitsgraphic.com/src/picto/Eye.png" class="social-media" alt="eye-logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="menubar">
                    <span class="first-span"></span>
                    <span class="second-span"></span>
                    <span class="third-span"></span>
                </div>

          </header>
          
         <div class="grille">
         
          
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this a simple answer of what you need , you are doing too much work.

maybe if you implement it simply it will work.

```js
window.onscroll = function (e) {
// print "false" if direction is down and "true" if up
if (this.oldScroll > this.scrollY) {
    document.querySelector("header").style.transform = "translateY(0px)"; 
} else {
    document.querySelector("header").style.transform = "translateY(-130px)";
}
this.oldScroll = this.scrollY; 
}
```

```css
header { 
background-color: red;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:100px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
transition: 0.5s; 
}

p { 
height: 250vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</header>

<p></p>
```